# a external monitor doesn't display all the colors in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, external-display

i have a laptop and external monitor setup. the problem is that in windows 7, the external monitor is displaying images really weird(256 colors i think). After the reboot, i see the display clear, but after one second everything on the external monitor turns to 256 colors (or less)

In the ubuntu the external monitor is acting just fine, even it is not recognized and is use a lower rezolution than the recommended one.

any advice?

ps: i've unistalled the monitors drivers in windows 7, but no improve.

many thanks!

Comment: What kind of monitor is it (how old, model)?  What kind of laptop (how old, model)?

Comment: it is a samsung syncmaster 225MW on a acer travelmate 5730

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your video drivers are up to date. Also make sure the refresh rate isn't set higher than what the monitor supports in that color mode / resolution.